# Why Postman send empty data in POST method

Tags: api, post, postman

When I develop `POST` api, I used `POSTMAN` I create following request

[image]

[image]

But it seems send empty request to servers.

When I check server, the following error was displayed

`Error: data and salt arguments required`

It means empty body was send via `POSTMAN`

On the other hand ,When I tried

`curl --data "loginId=hikaru&password=test" http://localhost:3000/user`

following error was occured but some data was send and reached

`ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'firstName' doesn't have a default value`

So what is the difference between `POSTMAN` and `command` ?

What is the wrong point of `postman`

I'd like to fix it.

If someone has opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You can export curl from Postman via the code button. Then you can compare the request from postman and the one you send from your command line,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl command in Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969183/curl-command-in-postman)