# curl command in Postman

Tags: api, post, postman

I developed `POST` api and tried to post via `POSTMAN`

I create following `POST` method.

But I send this data, empty data was send to server.

[image]

When I check code. the `curl` method was `line breaked`.

I guess this is the reason why the empty data was sent.

[image]

How can I fix it and send body ?

The following command send body data.

`curl --data "loginId=hikaru&password=test" http://localhost:3000/user`

line break is difference between them.

Thank you.

Comment: In the Settings of the code generator modal, you can select to generate the curl with or without linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks I wonder how can I modify `curl` command generated. it slightly different from my  command `curl --data "loginId=hikaru&password=test" http://localhost:3000/user`    As I am beginner, I'd like to know...

Comment: How does the curl postman generates look like?
The curl generated by Postman is exactly the request that Postman sends. So by midifying the Postman request, you're automatically modifiyong the curl it generates

Comment: the code generated is `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/user' --form 'loginId=hikaru' --form 'password=test'` I 'd like to know how to modify this code. But No matter how  I set `key` and `value`, it seems that the similar code will automatically be generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify curl post command in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975233/how-to-modify-curl-post-command-in-postman)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the comment you like to have the curl generated with
`--data "loginId=hikaru&password=test"`
Even though this might look like form-data it is a a raw body. To change the curl command generated follow these steps:

1. change the the body type from `form-data` to `raw`
2. enter `loginId=hikaru&password=test` as the body then Postman will generate the curl command you like to see